# Debug Toolbar Not Displaying on frontend

Tags: craft4, debugging

I just updated a site to Craft 4 and the debug toolbar no longer shows on the frontend, but does show in the CP. Have not had this issue with other sites that were updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if the HTML on the site’s front end is malformed. e.g. you have an opening body tag, but you’re missing the closing.

View the source on the page and run it through an HTML validator to verify.

Answer (score 1):

clearing caches / Forced browser reload is something that helps me out when it comes down to render changes..

Comment: Thanks, Stef - tried that but no luck. Even tried a browser on a different computer that I never use for dev, same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too obvious question, but.. did you check that checkmarks are set correctly for the debug tool in the account settings(My Account -> Preferences)?

Also, `devMode` is off/on on your website?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response - yes, all double checked.